# Correctly handle server.accept() exception

Tags: java, nio

How should I handle a `ServerSocket(Channel).accept()` exception? Is this exception can be thrown by client fault? In JavaDoc says only that:

```
IOException - If some other I/O error occurs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I handle a ServerSocket(Channel).accept() exception?

Close the channel. If you're supposed to be fault-tolerant, try to open a new one and continue accepting.

> Is this exception can be thrown by client fault?

No.

Comment: Server channel or client channel?

Comment: The one you got the exception on.

Answer (score 1):

How you handle is is completely up to you and your programs flow. We have all seen the message from a program stating "An unknown exception has occurred". This would likely be the IOException. Its the unknown other problem that can arise from transferring data. Of course they have these other exceptions you can catch that are more likely to come up and can be handled differently.

```
try {
    channel.accept();
} catch(NotYetBoundException e) {
    // If this channel's socket has not yet been bound
} catch(ClosedByInterruptException e) {
    // If another thread interrupts the current thread while the accept operation is in progress, thereby closing the channel and setting the current thread's interrupt status
} catch(AsynchronousCloseException e) {
    // If another thread closes this channel while the accept operation is in progress
} catch(ClosedChannelException e) {
    // If this channel is closed
} catch(SecurityException e) {
    // If a security manager has been installed and it does not permit access to the remote endpoint of the new connection
} catch(IOException e) {
    // If some other I/O error occurs
}
```

Comment: The only time you will see 'unknown exception' is in poorly written code that makes up its own messages like that, instead of using the exception itself and its own message.